# Mouse hover not working in WebView in NSPanel with styleMask of NSNonactivatingPanelMask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I created a NSPanel with styleMask of NSNonactivatingPanelMask. And I put an WebView in this NSPanel, and when I put mouse on some HTML buttons, I can't see any hover effect. I made this NSPanel key window and main window, but it doesn't help. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `NSPanel` must be the key window and the `WebView` must be the first responder:

```
[panel makeFirstResponder:webView];
```

This sounds like a bug to me because scrolling the web view even when it's not the first responder correctly highlights buttons with a hover effect.